# Show only rows that contain a certain text string, in any column

Tags: excel

My challenge: to **show only the rows that contain a certain text string, no matter which column that text string appears in**, even if the string is surrounded by other text (like finding the "mnd" inside "aac,mnd, jxt". Here's a simple example:

I have a spreadsheet of musicians who signed up to play some songs. Each row is a song. Each column is an instrument (guitar, bass, etc).

They add their initials to a cell. If someone else already signed up before them, they can add a comma and tack on their initials to the end. So, 2 guitarists on a song would look like "aac, mnd".

I need to show only the rows that have "mnd" (for example), so I can see all the songs she signed up for. But the "mnd" might appear in *any* column. Maybe on some songs, she plays bass, but on others, she plays guitar.

If she signed up later, her initials are tacked on like this: "aac, mnd,joe"

I need to see *all* rows that have "mnd" *anywhere*, even if there are commas, spaces, other text.

Is it possible? I'm using Excel or a Google spreadsheet (I don't care which). **I found ways to filter the rows based on *a single* column, but I need to filter based on a text string that could be in *any* column.** How?

Comment: With VBA, do a find over all `Cells()`, and then use the row it was found on, to hide the row.

Comment: Thanks! Could you be more specific, maybe just by pointing out something similar I could look at? I don't know VBA yet, but I've just begun exploring it now.

Comment: `pointing out something similar I could look at` google is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question. SO is not a free code-writing service. You're expected to describe what you have done to get to where you are now and show your code. There is a [great article about how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider reading it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say we have data in cols **A**, **B**, and **C**.

We want to see only rows containing *qwerty* somewhere in the row.

In **D2** enter:

```
=A2 &" "& B2 & " " & C2
```

and copy down.  In **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH("qwerty",D2,1),"")
```

and copy down.

Then set autofilter on column **E** to hide rows with blanks:

[image]

Comment: FWIW: without the first helper`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("qwerty",A2:C2))))`

Comment: Scott always with the best architecture.

Comment: I think I understand. I used Scott's code snippet to make a column that displays numbers (it shows a total count of the number of times my search string appears in that row). It doesn't produce blank rows, though. It puts 0 in if the search fails to find that string.

So, I just made a filter on that column and unchecked the 0 box. That's it!

Thanks! Sorry for all the edits. I keep hitting Enter for a new line. :)

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you could do something like this (brucewayne already commented this method)

```
Sub FindAndHide(LookingFor As String)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim RowContainsString As Boolean

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Arr = Rng.Value

LookingFor = LCase(LookingFor)

For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
    RowContainsString = False
    For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
        If InStr(LCase(Arr(i, j)), LookingFor) > 0 Then
            RowContainsString = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If Not RowContainsString Then Rng.Rows(i).Hidden = True
Next i

End Sub

Sub Test()
    FindAndHide LookingFor:="A"
End Sub
```

if the sheet has a large set of data then you could turn screen updating off or use Union to build the range that you want to hide and hide everything in 1 go.